# Trying to add functionality to JButton by adding JTextField data to array

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist

I'm trying to add data to my student array from the `JTextField` components. But I keep getting an error. I also don't know how to reference and use the variables from my student class within my `mainGui` class.

This is my GUI class

```
public class mainGui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   /**
    * Creates new form mainGui
    */
    ArrayList<Student> student = new ArrayList<>();

    public mainGui() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        sName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        sId = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        sYear = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        sEmail = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        sName.setText("jTextField1");

        jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");

        sId.setText("jTextField2");

        jLabel3.setText("jLabel3");

        sYear.setText("jTextField3");

        jLabel4.setText("jLabel4");

        sEmail.setText("jTextField4");
        sEmail.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                sEmailActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(sName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(sEmail, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(sId, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(sYear, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap(105, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(sName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(sId, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(sYear, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(sEmail, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(134, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here: 
         student.add(sEmail.getText());
         student.add(sYear.getText());
         student.add(sId.getText());
         student.add(sName.getText());        
    }
```

The student class

```
package student;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Student {

    ArrayList<Student> student = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private String sName;
    private int sID;
    private String sEmail;
    private int sYear;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here        
    }

    public Student(String studentName, int studentID, String studentEmail, int yearOfStudy)
    {
         this.sName = sName;
         this.sID = sID;
         this.sEmail = sEmail;
         this.sYear = sYear;    
    }
}
```

Comment: `"... but I keep getting an error"` -- What error? Where? This is somewhat important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your student ArrayList is of Student type, `ArrayList<Student>`, and so you can only add Student objects into it and not Strings as you're trying to do. Thus this won't compile:

```
     student.add(sEmail.getText());
     student.add(sYear.getText());
     student.add(sId.getText());
     student.add(sName.getText());
```

Instead get the Strings from your JTextFields, convert the Strings that need to be ints into ints, **create a Student object with the data**, and then add that student into your ArrayList.

in pseudo code:

```
// inside of actionPerformed:
get name String from sName, put into a String local variable
get email String from sEmail, put into a String local variable
get year String from sYear, convert to an int and put into a int local variable
get id String from sID, convert to an int and put into a int local variable

create a Student object from the local variables
add to student ArrayList
```

side recommendations:

- Rename the student ArrayList  to students or studentsList
- Get that student `ArrayList<Student>` out of your Student class. It shouldn't be in there, and will only cause trouble if you leave it in.
- Give your Student class accessor (getter) methods so that outside classes can find the state of its fields.